# Assigning #define macros to variable

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am trying to change some code but am running into issues. Here are the existing lines:

```
#define AHB1PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00020000UL)
#define GPIOF_BASE            (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1400UL)
#define GPIOF               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOF_BASE)
#define SSD1306_CS_Port         GPIOF
```

I want to make SSD1306_CS_Port a variable and change the value in real time.

Thanks!

I tried:

```
GPIO_TypeDef *SSD1306_CS_Port = GPIOF;
```

But got an error about expansion of macro. What am I not getting here?

Comment: `But got an error about expansion of macro` What errors? `I want to make SSD1306_CS_Port a variable` Please post the full code _after_ the change.

Comment: If you're asking about a compiler error message, always include the message (copy-and-pasted) in the question, formatted as code.

Comment: Sounds like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: `SSD1306_CS_Port` is both a macro name and a variable name. In your declaration `GPIO_TypeDef *SSD1306_CS_Port = GPIOF;`, the identifier `SSD1306_CS_Port` is expanded, which will probably cause a syntax error. Use distinct identifiers. And for future reference, please provide a [mre] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer can't have the same name as macro.

```
GPIO_TypeDef *SSD1306_CS_Port = GPIOF;
```

^^^^^ It is invalid

The name has to be distinct

```
GPIO_TypeDef *SSD1306_CS_Port_ptr = GPIOF;
```

You do not need to declare this pointer (it is even wrong as you add another level of indirection and use SRAM). Simple use:

```
SSD1306_CS_Port -> ODR |= SSD1306_CS_Pin;
//you need to define SSD1306_CS_Pin as well of course
//same with other GPIO registers
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this is an stm32 project using HAL drivers. The first 3 lines are from the HAL drivers to show the defines behind the issue. The forth line is from the code I am trying to change.

Comment: @Madhun2020 you do not need to define this variable.

Comment: To clarify: there is no general rule that a macro name cannot appear in a variable in a declaration.  The OP's code is invalid because after macro expansion, the line in question is not a valid declaration.  With a different macro definition, that might not have been the case.

Comment: The renaming trick worked! Not sure why is tas needed but I'll take it!

Comment: @Madhun2020 It was needed because macros specify simple textual replacement, regardless of context. The preprocessor (which handles macro definitions and expansions) runs doesn't recognize C syntax. If you write `#define FOO 42`, then a following `int FOO;` expands to `int 42;`, which is a syntax error.